# Silverlight OOB with authenticaton

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a silverlight application and we are planning to have NT authentication for the website on the IIS. This application however has support for Out of browser as well. Will the user be challenged for NT password when launched from OOB?

Answer (score 0):

I have an application that runs both in and out of the browser and accesses ASP.NET services via NT authentication. Everything seems to work just fine.